# I am trying to write a while loop in javascript. My console.log does not print the requested message

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```js
var ask = prompt('Are we there yet???');

while (ask != 'y') {

  if (ask[0] === 'y') {
    // For some unknown reason to me my solution will not print the message.
    console.log('Yea, we made it!!!');
  } else {
    var ask = prompt('Are we there yet???');
  };

}
```

Comment: if you answer `y` the first time the loop never happens - if you answer `y` the second or subsequent time, the loop terminates - if you answer `yes` any time (or anything that starts with `y` and has 1 or more characters after it), the loop *infinitely* logs `yeah we made it` - never asking for another input, because `ask` never equals `y` but `ask[0]` always equals `y`

Comment: You don't need to do it with while, you can call `prompt` then, if the result is what you're looking for, call to `console` and if, show the `prompt` again (very similar to what you're doing now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is setting a variable inside of the while loop to the output of the prompt which is why the loop can't access it.

To achieve your goal, you'll need something like this:

```js
while (prompt('Are we there yet???') !== 'y') {}
console.log('Yea, we made it!!!');
```

Basically, the code goes in an infinite loop of asking the user to type `y` before continuing the code and in this case, logging the message to the console.